# How to Access the Collider Just Triggered when there are multiple colliders on a GameObject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Learning Unity right now and have run into a problem regarding colliders. I find it very strange that there is no way to access the current collider activated in an `OnTriggerEnter` function. It gives you reference to the other collider, but there is absolutely no way to access the collider that is from the current game object. The thing is most of the time (if you only have one collider) you can just get a reference to it by `GetComponent`. However, I have two Circle Colliders, and even though I can get a reference to both using `GetComponents`, I have no way of knowing which one is triggering the function. How can I know which collider is triggering what?